# Windows Mobile 6.5 file system crash Motorola MC55 when running .NET CF 3.5 application

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I have issues with .NET CF 3.5 application on Windows Mobile 6.5 on Motorola MC55 device. We have around 150 devices which run a barcode scanning application written in C# Compact Framework 3.5. The application is for barcode scanning and communication with SOAP WebService through WIFI/GPRS. Every day around 10-15 devices go corrupted (file system errors) and need to be flashed again. Motorola support claims it is a fault of our application. For us this is not an argument. What can be source of the problem?
The application is a simple Windows Forms application written in CF C# 3.5 which uses System.XML, System.Net, OpenNETCF and EMDK assemblies. It scan barcodes, connects to a SOAP WebService using HTTP and sends/receives data from external server. Additionally, it synchronizes system time using PInvoke API calls. File system is used by reading/writing XML files using System.XML assemblies. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Does the same issue exist if you deploy it to other devices, or the emulator?

Comment: Have you gone through the code trying to identify the exact functionality that is causing the corruption? I know you say it's the file system, but during what process? Like you say what you're doing doesn't sound anything special so there's no reason to think it would be problematic.

Comment: add a routine to check how much memory you have left,it could be a memory leak, that leaves the system out of space, so when you try to write the file the file system gets corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably related to the time sync. The OS has a maximum limit of 32 processes - a time change event kicks off up to 5 additional processes, clocknot, calnot etc. If you're up near 25, 26 processes when the time change event occurs the device/app can lock as the OS tries to close processes.

The standard user response is to dump the battery and if this happens before a write is complete - hey presto - the device is corrupt.